# how to use jQuery to show and hide HTML using html buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms

(i will be as descriptive as possible, let be know if you need more info in the comments)

hi!

I don't know what jQuery is and what it does, a guy at SO told me that it does what i what to do.

This is what is want to do:

i have 5 different sentences, lets use these as an example:

- sentence 01
- sentence 02
- sentence 03
- sentence 04
- sentence 05

what i wanna do is show 1 sentence at a time. and when a user presses a next button, next sentence should show up, and first sentence should hide, and then if user presses next again then 3rd sentence should show up and second sentence should hide.

I want to do this in one page, meaning that the next button should not link to another page where the next sentence is.

There should also be a previous button, and if a user is watching 2nd sentence and he wants to go back to the first.

please note that i should be able to enter any html code, not just a sentence, i used it for an example.

And, if i wanna add some more html code (like sentence 6), i can just add it on my html file and if i click next again, it should popup and i don't have to change any jQuery everytime i add more stuff in.

If you think jQuery can't do all this then let me know how its done. THANKS... I know that this is a little too much, if a volunteer wants to help me, it will be a great honor.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: i have tried using javascript but failed,

Comment: here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Fs73d/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

Assuming we've got HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type=button id=prevBtn value="Prev" />
    <input type=button id=nextBtn value="Next" />
    <div id=sentences>
      <p>Sentence 1</p>
      <p>Sentence 2</p>
      <p>Sentence 3</p>
      <p>Sentence 4</p>
      <p>Sentence 5</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And CSS that hides all the sentences unless they've got a class of 'current' (mystyles.css):

```
#sentences * {
    display: none;
}
#sentences .current {
    display: inline;
}
```

Then this code will do what you want (myscript.js):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#sentences *').eq(0).addClass('current'); // start by showing the first sentence
    $('#nextBtn, #prevBtn').click(function() {
        var currItem = $('#sentences .current');
        var newItem = ($(this).attr('id') == 'nextBtn') ? currItem.next() : currItem.prev();
        if (newItem.size() > 0) {
            currItem.removeClass('current');
            newItem.addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, we start by giving the `current` class to the first item in the list.
Then we've got a click-handler that finds the current item, and moves either `next()` or `prev()` depending on which button was pressed. If that resulted in a valid item (we're not at the beginning/end of the list), then we remove the `current` class from the current item, and add it to the new one we found.

Fiddle for this solution is here: http://jsfiddle.net/39CYu/

Comment: i know how to add css to HTML, but i dont know how to add jquery to HTMl... sorry i am dumb

Comment: Yes, that will work. Don't forget to also include the jquery library itself (first).

Comment: jQuery is a library (javascript script) that helps make HTML document manipulation simpler. You include it in your page just like any other script. I've updated my solution to show the actual code to include the CSS and javascript code, including loading jQuery directly from the Google-hosted libraries.

Comment: i saw the fiddle, when i am another <p> at the bottom, it works fine. but when i added an <h1>, it stopped working

Comment: I've updated the fiddle (new link), and my code to work with any element type/

Comment: You are a genius, that worked perfectly, that's just what i need.

Comment: one more question, is there a way to store your coding files, like CSS and JS on a website, so you can link to it easily?

Comment: It sounds like you need a web host. Something like **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/hosting/default.asp)** or **[this](http://www.websiteblueprint.com/what-is-a-web-host/)** should help you understand what you're looking for.

Comment: lol, i already have a web host, but i use a CMS so i don't really store coding files

Answer (score 1):

You can use a content slider jQuery  plugin like

http://bxslider.com/

It's easy to use

**html**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>My text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>text3</li>
  <li>Another text</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

and of course it is jQuery based

Comment: this looks if you have images. Do you have any other plugins. I want a visible "next button"

Comment: you can use it with text also

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this. use an array of strings where you will store all the sentences. And 
a variable to store the current index of the String which is being shown.

`var arr = ["sentence 1", "sentence 2", "sentence 3", "sentence 4", "sentence 5"];
var currPos = 0;`.

Then when the user click on the prev button, you can do something like this,

`$('#prev').on('click', function(e){
    currPos--;
    currPos = Math.abs(currPos);
    var currStr = arr[currPos];
    $('#text').innerHtml = currStr;
});` 
and when the user clicks on next button you can do something like this,

`$('#next').on('click', function(e){
    currPos++;
    currPos = Math.abs(currPos);
    var currStr = arr[currPos];
    $('#text').innerHtml = currStr;
});`

Comment: can you fiddle this for me, i am confused